# Why the commands written in a .bat running infinitely in java?

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

I have a `.bat` file whose job to find the version of the java. The command written inside the bat file is `java -version` (This is just an example, don't suggest alternative ways to get java version)

Code to run the `.bat` file:

```
String path = "cmd /c start d:\\java.bat"; 
Runtime rn = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rn.exec(path);
```

The bat file is running but running in a loop. But the expected behavior is it should open the command prompt and run the command only once

Comment: The `java` command in the batch file runs `java.bat` since it first looks for a `.exe` or `.cmd` or `.bat` in the current directory before looking in the `PATH`. Rename your batch file `findJavaVersion.bat` and it should then work.

Comment: I just gave an example. Its applicable for all the commands

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou: It didnt work for me after renaming the bat file name

Comment: @mfsi_sudhansu what is the behaviour after the name change? It shouldn't call itself at least, is there another trouble you are having?

Comment: @mfsi_sudhansu remove  `cmd /c start` part, since that starts a separate subprocess, just keep `d:\\java.bat` since that counts as an executable alone, than you can get its output in your java application

Answer (score 6):

Because the name of the file is same as the command within it, the `java.bat` file is itself called from the `java -version` command. Just renaming the `.bat` file, or using `java.exe -version` would stop the issue.

Since extension for such executables and batch files is optional (*), the filename itself can be used alone as a command, read more about it [here](https://ict.senecacollege.ca/~albert.pang/ios100/dosbatch.html)

(*) check great in-depth comment by @Compo

---

> Also here is an example [Java Bat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minute_fruit_bat) =)

Comment: Technically, the extensions are not optional, the file `java` is searched for in the current directory with any of the extensions listed under `%PATHEXT%` e.g. `.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;etc....` and in the same order first to last, _(stopping at the first found.)_. If none are found in the current directory, the locations listed under `%PATH%` are searched. This means that when searching for `java` in the line, `java -version`, it finds `java.bat` in the current directory. The quickest fixes, could be use `java.exe -version` or to change the [tag:batch-file] name to be more unique.

Answer (score 2):

check java library instead of using a `.bat` file

```
Version version = java.lang.Runtime.version();
System.out.println("Java Version = "+version);
System.out.println("Java Version Feature Element = "+version.feature());
System.out.println("Java Version Interim Element = "+version.interim());
System.out.println("Java Patch Element Version = "+version.patch());
System.out.println("Java Update Element Version = "+version.update());
System.out.println("Java Version Build = "+version.build().get());
System.out.println("Java Pre-Release Info = "+version.pre().orElse("NA"));
```

here is [source](https://www.journaldev.com/20930/check-java-version)

Comment: Perfect, no tremendous overhead of a process with cmd; platform independent. And usage of a rare API jem. The formulation could be better: "No need to run a cmd.exe as java has access to its `Runtime.version()`." Or so.

Comment: This only works on Java 9 and above. For Java 8 and below, use the `java.version` system property.

Comment: I think both type answer should available here ! some users wants to use java library then this answer will help them ! in the given question  user asked about java version with .bat but i want to suggest him, you can also use this if its usable to you !

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer myself.. 
in stead of writing the commands simply in the bat file we can write in the below way and it worked for me

call java -version

Thanks,
Sudhansu

Comment: Do you mean just executing `java -version`  on command line? Without running a Java application?